# ¿Cómo hacer una función que reste dos strings (que se eliminen los carácteres que se repitan) en C++?

Tags: c++, string, funciones, bucle-for

Quiero hacer una función que elimine los carácteres repetidos entre dos strings, pero sólo una vez, por ejemplo:
Palabra1 = "avioncito"
Palabra2 = "avion"

PalabraRestante = "cito"

Lo malo es que al hacer el código, parece que elimina todos los carácteres existentes del mismo tipo (puesto que en mi código sólo queda "ct"

A continuación mi código:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


int getTamanioPalabra(string cadena2){
  int tamanioPalabra;
  tamanioPalabra = cadena2.size(); 
  return tamanioPalabra;
}


int main() {
  string palabra = "avioncito";
  string cadena2 = "avion";

  for(int i=0; i<getTamanioPalabra(cadena2); i++){
    for(int j=0; j<getTamanioPalabra(cadena2); j++){
      if(palabra[i]==cadena2[j]){
        palabra[i]=' ';
        for(int k=i; k<getTamanioPalabra(palabra); k++){
          palabra[k] = palabra[k+1];
          palabra[k+1] = '\0';
        }
      }
    }
  } 

  cout<<palabra<<endl;

  return 0;

}
```

Gracias por su ayuda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para que solo se realice un reemplazo, basta con usar un `break` que haga que la ejecución abandone el bucle de reemplazo.

Eso y un par de ajustes más y listo

```
for( char c : cadena2)
{
  for( int i=0; i<getTamanioPalabra(palabra); i++ )
  {
    if( c == palabra[i] )
    {
      for( int j=i; j<getTamanioPalabra(palabra); j++ )
        palabra[j] == palabra[j+1];
      i--; // Hay que retroceder una posición para comprobar el primer caracter que hemos movido
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, sólo hacía falta utilizar un break

Answer (score 1):

No necesitas reinventar la rueda, sólo debes buscar la cadena en la palabra y eliminarla si existe:

```
// Busca 'cadena2' en 'palabra'
auto found = palabra.find(cadena2);

// Si existe...
if (found != string::npos)
{
    // ... borrar desde la posición encontrada todas las letras de 'cadena'.
    palabra.erase(found, cadena2.length());
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY5LbsMwDETX0ilYd2MDTVB0GTu5CyPRjgCbEvRZBTm7Q9VxuigEQsTMG5ImhIOZkad1/XRs5mIJBudTjoTLRf9pojieLrok@YBxoRTQEKRse60dZ1jQcdvBXauNhYAzXiPCGRoM8syNmv7tGrTE@FPdaoqjlfElwzC8k9I2cJCSZud/NQlVHkv2MPrCVpRX6Dg6tu2L7irlRmg36OMM2/bTiYNPnVZyrdqDFDHRRn7t644z8ZRvbSeT1OP/iXV@pFwiw3evH@v6BA)</kbd>.